# When use PyPlot as backend of Plot.jl in Jupyter Notebook how to set svg output

Tags: matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook, julia

When I set `pyplot()` as the backend of Plots.jl, the Jupyter notebook output is png rather than svg,

Even I using `PyPlot.svg(true)` to set the output format as svg, the Plots.jl still using png output

This is the code I actually use

```
using Plots
pyplot()
PyPlot.svg(true)
df2 = CSV.read("0048_plot.csv") |> DataFrame
plot(df2[1],df2[2],title="YBCO Diamagnetism \n Phase Transition (Varies with External Field)",
        label="Magnitisation",
        xlabel="Temperature (K)", 
        ylabel="Long Magnetic Moment (Emu)"
        )
scatter!(df2[1], df2[2], label="Data Point",framestyle=:box)
```

and the result
[png output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i55Nf.png)

Comment: Your code doesn't contain a call to `savefig`, so how could you be getting any output? That aside, try using a `.svg` extension to the filename in your `savefig` call. That works for the `gr()` backend so hopefully...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're saving a figure, colin's response in the comment is correct. In Jupyter or other interactive settings, use `plot(df2[1],df2[2],format = :svg)`. You may want to check out StatPlots and the `@df` macro for plotting data in dataframes.